# How can I calculate a trajectory of hitting a bike ramp

Tags: calculus

I seen a video of a person hitting a bike ramp and it failed horribly, the ramp was just a piece of wood on a white pale. I started wondering how much worse it could have been if they hit the jump successfully and fell off the bike in mid air so I started calculating.

I did some guestimations and figure the ramp was something like

Adjacent 18"
Opposite 36"
Hypotenuse 40"
Angle of jump about 26.6°

And figure they were probably moving at about 3m/s

(I am by no means an expert in trig, or really math for this matter)

Then I found this Range formula

R=(3)^2(sin 2*26.6)/9.8

Which gave me R=1.7m so had they made the jump they would have traveled 1.7m through the air.

But now I want to figure out how to calculate their maximum height. I tried googling it but I keep finding stuff related to people just jumping with their feet straight up in the air unrelated to what I want to find. Or even plot a trajectory so I can see at what distance they're at what height

Can somebody point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Not sure what tag to use for question, feel free to edit.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You are guesstimating that the ramp angle is about $26.6^\circ$?  That is an incredibly precise guestimation.  The formula for altitude, which you should find somewhere early in your physics book is $y(t) = v_0 \sin\theta t   - \frac 12 g t^2, y_{max}$ is at the time $t$ such that  $t = \frac {v_0 \sin\theta}{g}$

Comment: @DougM I just got 26.6 from using trig with my guessed heights

Comment: @DougM did the drive under the ramp, the height of the ramp is roughly 18" how can they be at 3" after jumping it

Comment: 3" above the top of the ramp.